# How to create this update query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I construct an update query that will go through the following table and put any col2 and col3 on the same row if they have the same "date" values?

```
ID col1  col2   col3  date
33  10                3/2/2010
35  NULL  200   NULL  3/2/2010
40  NULL  NULL  300   3/2/2010
43  10                3/5/2010
45  NULL  200   NULL  3/7/2010
46  NULL  NULL  310   3/8/2010
53  10                3/9/2010
55  NULL  200   NULL  3/10/2010
58  NULL  NULL  400   3/10/2010
```

New arrangement:

```
ID col1  col2   col3  date
33  10                3/2/2010
35  NULL  200   300   3/2/2010
43  10                3/5/2010
45  NULL  200   NULL  3/7/2010
46  NULL  NULL  310   3/8/2010
53  10                3/9/2010
55  NULL  200   400   3/10/2010
```

Notice the change for dates 3/2/2010 and 3/10/2010 for col2 and col3 only.  These are on the same row and the extra/old entries have been deleted.

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: So you need `UPDATE` and `DELETE` then? Why did the row with `ID=33` survived?

Comment: He only wants to combine col 2 and col 3 that are containing the same date

Comment: What is the version of SQLServer ?

Comment: Are we guaranteed that `col1` in rows to combine is `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Current Data**

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ col1 ║ col2 ║ col3 ║    date    ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬════════════╣
║ 33 ║ 10   ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 2010-03-02 ║
║ 35 ║ NULL ║ 200  ║ NULL ║ 2010-03-02 ║
║ 40 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 300  ║ 2010-03-02 ║
║ 43 ║ 10   ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 2010-03-05 ║
║ 45 ║ NULL ║ 200  ║ NULL ║ 2010-03-07 ║
║ 46 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 310  ║ 2010-03-08 ║
║ 53 ║ 10   ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 2010-03-09 ║
║ 55 ║ NULL ║ 200  ║ NULL ║ 2010-03-10 ║
║ 58 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 400  ║ 2010-03-10 ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩════════════╝
```

**Queries**

*Update Records*

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Col2 = T2.Col2,
    T1.Col3 = T2.Col3
FROM Table_Name T1 INNER JOIN Table_Name T2
ON T1.[date] = T2.[date]
WHERE T1.col1 IS  NULL
```

*Delete Records*

```
;WITH Deletebles
AS
  (
   SELECT * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER (PARTITION BY Col2, Col3,[Date] ORDER BY [Date])
   FROM @t
  )
  DELETE FROM Deletebles
  WHERE rn >1
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ col1 ║ col2 ║ col3 ║    date    ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬════════════╣
║ 33 ║ 10   ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 2010-03-02 ║
║ 35 ║ NULL ║ 200  ║ 300  ║ 2010-03-02 ║
║ 43 ║ 10   ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 2010-03-05 ║
║ 45 ║ NULL ║ 200  ║ NULL ║ 2010-03-07 ║
║ 46 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 310  ║ 2010-03-08 ║
║ 53 ║ 10   ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 2010-03-09 ║
║ 55 ║ NULL ║ 200  ║ 400  ║ 2010-03-10 ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not only updating, you're deleting as well. If you don't want to write a procedure for that, i guess the best way is select the result and insert it into a temporary table - then possibly drop the original table and rename the temporary one.

```
insert into temptable
select min(id), col1, max(col2), max(col3), date
from origtable
group by col1, date
```

Edit: removed the max from col1 since you seem to want only col2 and col3 considered.

Comment: How would you handle the deletes?

Comment: @4thSpace: a bit modified version that deletes using `MERGE` : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/354e8/43

Answer (score -1):

I don't think update query will be sufficient because you have to remove/delete rows. Here is the **select** statement that'll give you what you need... but now you'll need to decide if you want to selectively delete unnecessary rows or drop all and re-populate with the new values.

**EDIT**: looks like I've made an assumption that there could be more than one row for Col1 (hence the **union**) If the dupes in Col1 can be eliminated, you can simple add Col1 in the group by.

```
SELECT ID, COL1, NULL AS COL2, NULL AS COL3, [DATE]
FROM TBL
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, NULL AS COL1, MAX(COL2), MAX(COL3), [DATE]
FROM TBL
WHERE COL2 IS NOT NULL OR COL3 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [DATE]
```

I've used this to test...

```
create table tbl (id int, col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, [date] date)

insert into tbl
values (33,10,null,null,'3/2/2010'),
(35,NULL,200,NULL,'3/2/2010'),
(40,NULL,NULL,300,'3/2/2010'),
(43,10,null,null,'3/5/2010'),
(45,NULL,200,NULL,'3/7/2010'),
(46,NULL,NULL,310,'3/8/2010'),
(53,10,null,null,'3/9/2010'),
(55,NULL,200,NULL,'3/10/2010'),
(58,NULL,NULL,400,'3/10/2010')
```